# how to join 2 tables based upon Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.
1st Table looks like below

```
    session_start_dt  |  package_key
-------------------------------------------
   01-01-2015        |  202
   01-02-2015        |  203
   01-14-2016        |  204
   12-01-2015        |  206
   03-02-2015        |  204
   04-14-2016        |  202
```

2nd table looks like below

```
package_key     |  term_start_date    |   term_end_date  | Active | event
 202             |  01-01-2014         |   01-01-2015     | Y     | NS
 202             |  01-01-2014         |   01-01-2015     | Y     | CAN
 203             |  01-02-2015         |   01-02-2016     | N     | NS
 204             |  01-02-2015         |   01-02-2016     | N     | NS
 206             |  01-02-2015         |   01-02-2016     | N     | NS
 206             |  01-01-2014         |   01-01-2015     | Y     | NS
```

I need to get all the records from the 1st table and get if he is active or not from the 2nd table when the session_start_dt falls between the term_start_date and term_end_date of the 2nd table.

```
session_start_dt   |  package_key | Active
-------------------------------------------
 01-01-2015        |  202         |  Y
 01-02-2015        |  203         |  N
 01-14-2016        |  204         |  null
 12-01-2015        |  206         |  N
 03-02-2015        |  204         |  N
 04-14-2016        |  202         |  null
```

I am writing the query like

```
select package_key, session_start_dt from table a, table b 
where SESSION_START_Dt BETWEEN TERM_START_DATE AND TERM_END_DATE AND 
PACKAGE_KEY = PACKAGE_KEY and event not in ('CAN')
```

and it's not giving the      desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `between` for `join` conditions.  I think this is the logic you want:

```
select t1.*, t2.active
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.package_key = t2.package_key and
        t1.session_start_dt between t2.term_start_date and t2.term_end_date;
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff - how can we write the same query with (+) operator?

Comment: @beckham . . . You shouldn't do that.  Use explicit outer join syntax.  And try to forget that you every learned something like `(+)`.

Comment: Missing: `and event not in ('CAN')` - which by the way is the same as `and event != 'CAN'`.

Comment: @mathguy - I didn't get you. Can you please explain?

Comment: I said two things. One is that compared to what you were trying to do, Gordon's solution is missing a `WHERE` condition. The other thing I said was that `event not in ('CAN')` is the same as `event != 'CAN'`. `IN` is more helpful when you have several items (it saves you typing a lot of `OR` operations), but with only one item you don't need it.